# How to implement scrolling images with mouse cursor click in js and css3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to do something like this http://www.romeoshagba.com/#1
Please help.

This is my code

The CSS CODE

```
.gree
{
background: #333;
width: max-content;
 white-space: nowrap;
height:38em;
position: relative;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: auto;
}
.gree img
{
height:100%;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
}
```

Here is a sample of the php file that get images from database

```
<div class="gree padding_20-bottom">

        <?php
        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 30");
      {

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2))
    {
         $photo2 = $row2['photo_link'];

         echo"<img src='$photo2'>";
    }
      }
    ?>

    </div>
```

My main issue is getting the mouse position and the click to centre the next image

Comment: tried using bootstrap carousel but not working like that. I guess it was implemented with js. I just need help executing something like that. designing a website for a client

Comment: Could you please post the code you've tried so far, instead of just saying you've tried bootstrap carousel we would like to see some code.

Comment: Also please read: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: position "fixed" for everything else (header, footer) and put all images on the same line. ps. put them in a css table. this will create page scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

**It would have been easier to help you if you share the code**

Anyways you can try this:

1. Have all the images lined horizontally ( you can use float left) in a container and set the overflow value hidden
2. split the container into two (do the math). Find the cursor position using javascript or try using
   [jquery mouse wheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel). If the cursor is in Left container customize the cursor image to point left vice versa.
3. For every click move the container to some pixels.